# Online Shop with Ajax support to filter products

Tags: ajax, wordpress, e-commerce, shopp

I've searched the internet and couldn't find a free (or not very expensive) solution that offers the following behavior: I would like to set up an online shop where the user can click checkboxes to refine the selection of products, like on [asos.com](http://www.asos.com/Men/Accessories/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=4210).

As it's not going to be a huge shop, I plan to use Wordpress together with the [Shopp Plugin](http://shopplugin.net/). What I now need is that extra Ajax part to refresh the product list based on the selection the user makes.

Does anyone know a plugin that has this behavior built-in? Or can someone point me to a tutorial or similar? I'm pretty new to Ajax but familiar with jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you found something, but I can confirm that Shopp does have filtering - they call it 'Faceted Menus' but that as far as I can see (just tested it) it's not Ajax and reloads the page.